Show that if $0$ if the only eigenvalue of $A\in\text{Mat}_{n,n}(\mathbb C)$, then $A$ is nilpotent.
Here is the provided solution:
We know that $\mathbb C^n$ has a basis $(v_1,\dots, v_n)$, where each $v_i$ is a generalised eigenvector of $A$ (a vital part of the proof to the Jordan Canonical form). Since the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $0$, saying that $v_1$ is a generalised eigenvector of $A$ is the same as saying $A^{k_i}v_i=0$ for some $k_i≥1$. Then if we let $k=\max \{k_1,...,k_n\}$, we have $A^kv_i=0$ for all $i$, so $A^k$ is the zero matrix.
Here is my proof:
If $0$ were the unique eigenvalue of $A$, then $Av=0v=\underline0$ for some $0$-eigenvector $v$. Thus, $A$ is equivalent to a zero-map. Then trivially, $A^kv=0^kv=0v=\underline 0$, and since $v≠0$ by definition of eigenvectors, we have $A^k=0$ for some $k≥1$ as required.
I was wondering if their posted solution is overcomplicating it, and whether my proof is acceptable? If not, where is the flaw in my proof?

"$Av=0$ for some $v$" does not imply "$A$ is a zero map." A Jordan block with zeros on the diagonal is a counterexample.

Out of curiosity, can you please include a link to 'their posted solution'?

@angryavian but don't we still have $Av=0\implies A^kv=0$ (since $Av=\lambda v\implies A^k v=\lambda^k v$ in general), and since $v≠0$ by the definition of an eigenvector, $A^k=0$?

@AnneBauval It is part of my classes' problem set solutions, so I'm assuming my professor/tutors made it.

$Bv=0$ and $v\ne0$ does not imply $B=0$. This is the flaw in your proof.

A more elementary approach is to consider the minimal polynomial $m(x)$ of $A$. Since every zero of $m(x)$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and all eigenvalues of $A$ are assumed to be zero, $m(x)$ must be in the form of $x^k$ for some integer $k\ge1$. Therefore $A^k=0$.

Use  Cayley-Hamilton theorem. Since all eigenvalues are $0$, the characteristic polynomial  is $x^n$.

@fusheng That was my last comment but I deleted it, since user1551's argument is more elementary.

the most basic approach is to manipulate rank inequalities of the form $\text{rank}\big(A\big)\geq \text{rank}\big(A^2\big)\geq \text{rank}\big(A^3\big)\geq \dots$ and if you ever have equality $\text{rank}\big(A^k\big)=\text{rank}\big(A^{k+1}\big)\gt 0$ then argue $\implies \text{rank}\big(A^k\big)=\text{rank}\big(A^{2k}\big)\implies V=\ker A^k \oplus \text{image }A^k$ i.e. $(A^k)\mathbf B =\mathbf B\left[\begin{array}{cc} \mathbf 0 &\mathbf 0 \ \mathbf 0 & C \end{array} \right]$ where $C$ is injective yet has an eigenvalue zero, impossible $\implies\text{rank}\big(A^n\big)=0$
